# How do I know my view gets frontmost/covered?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller with some kind of internal processing that is only supposed to be run while the view controller’s view is frontmost. There used to be a convenient convention that one could start such processing in `viewDidAppear(_:)` and stop it in `viewWillDisappear(_:)`.

But nowadays the view can also be covered by another translucent view controller, in which case it’s still on the screen (`viewWillDisappear(_:)` is not called), but at the same time it’s not frontmost.

Is there a simple, bullet-proof way of knowing when such situation happens? In other words, I would love to have something like `viewWillResignActive` and `viewWillBecomeActive`. Without having to override `presentViewController(_:animated:completion:)` and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with a custom `UINavigationController` subclass and trapped the presentation and dismissal methods:

```
protocol ViewActivityDelegate {

    func viewWillBecomeCovered()
    func viewDidBecomeCovered()
    func viewWillBecomeRevealed()
    func viewDidBecomeRevealed()
}

class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        let delegate = topViewController as? ViewActivityDelegate
        delegate?.viewWillBecomeCovered()
        super.presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag) {
            completion?()
            delegate?.viewDidBecomeCovered()
        }
    }

    override func dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        let delegate = topViewController as? ViewActivityDelegate
        delegate?.viewWillBecomeRevealed()
        super.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag) {
            completion?()
            delegate?.viewDidBecomeRevealed()
        }
    }
}
```